# Scala: identify n rows before and n rows when a condition is satisfied in a window

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scala dataframe.

I want to treat each `id` separately.

For each `id` ordered by `datetime`, whenever a condition is satisfied in `cond` column (`$"cond" === 1`) ,

I want to create `ans` column for identifying n rows before and after the condition.

e.g. ideal case:

```
val df = Seq(
  (101, "2020-01-01", 0),
  (101, "2020-02-01", 0),
  (101, "2020-03-01", 0),
  (101, "2020-04-01", 0),
  (220, "2020-01-01", 0),
  (220, "2020-01-05", 0),
  (220, "2020-01-10", 0),
  (220, "2020-01-15", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-01", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-05", 1),
  (220, "2020-02-10", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-15", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-20", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-25", 0)
).toDF("id", "datetime", "cond")
```

answer should be (with n=3)

```
val ans = Seq(
  (101, "2020-01-01", 0, "0"),
  (101, "2020-02-01", 0, "0"),
  (101, "2020-03-01", 0, "0"),
  (101, "2020-04-01", 0, "0"),
  (220, "2020-01-01", 0, "0"),
  (220, "2020-01-05", 0, "0"),
  (220, "2020-01-10", 0, "before"),
  (220, "2020-01-15", 0, "before"),
  (220, "2020-02-01", 0, "before"),
  (220, "2020-02-05", 1, "at"),
  (220, "2020-02-10", 0, "after"),
  (220, "2020-02-15", 0, "after"),
  (220, "2020-02-20", 0, "after"),
  (220, "2020-02-25", 0,  "0")
).toDF("id", "datetime", "cond", "ans")
```

Edge case: problem when two (`$"cond" === 1`) are overlapping with specified n:

```
val df = Seq(
  (101, "2020-01-01", 0),
  (101, "2020-02-01", 0),
  (101, "2020-03-01", 0),
  (101, "2020-04-01", 0),
  (220, "2020-01-01", 0),
  (220, "2020-01-05", 0),
  (220, "2020-01-10", 0),
  (220, "2020-01-15", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-01", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-05", 1),
  (220, "2020-02-10", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-15", 1),
  (220, "2020-02-20", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-25", 0),
  (220, "2020-02-26", 0)
).toDF("id", "datetime", "cond")
```

answer should be with n = 4

```
val edge = Seq(
  (101, "2020-01-01", 0, "0"),
  (101, "2020-02-01", 0, "0"),
  (101, "2020-03-01", 0, "0"),
  (101, "2020-04-01", 0, "0"),
  (220, "2020-01-01", 0, "0"),
  (220, "2020-01-05", 0, "before"),
  (220, "2020-01-10", 0, "before"),
  (220, "2020-01-15", 0, "before"),
  (220, "2020-02-01", 0, "before"),
  (220, "2020-02-05", 1, "at"),
  (220, "2020-02-10", 0, "between"),
  (220, "2020-02-15", 1, "at"),
  (220, "2020-02-20", 0, "after"),
  (220, "2020-02-25", 0, "after"),
  (220, "2020-02-26", 0, "after")
).toDF("id", "datetime", "cond", "ans")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach for the ideal case. I'll leave the edge case as an exercise.

The approach here is to add another column with indices so we can get the index of the row where `cond == 1`. From there it is just a matter of using that index to update the proper row and column using `withColumn` and chained `when` statements. Lastly, `select` the columns we want to keep for the final output.

```
val df_withIndices = df.withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id())

val atIndex = df_withIndices.filter(df("cond") === 1).select("index").head.getLong(0)
println(atIndex)

df_withIndices
  .withColumn("ans", when(col("cond") === 1,  lit("at"))
    .when(col("index") === atIndex - 3 , "before")
    .when(col("index") === atIndex - 2 , "before")
    .when(col("index") === atIndex - 1 , "before")
    .when(col("index") === atIndex + 1, "after")
    .when(col("index") === atIndex + 2 , "after")
    .when(col("index") === atIndex + 3 , "after")
    .otherwise("0"))
  .select("id", "datetime", "cond", "ans")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+----+------+
| id|  datetime|cond|   ans|
+---+----------+----+------+
|101|2020-01-01|   0|     0|
|101|2020-02-01|   0|     0|
|101|2020-03-01|   0|     0|
|101|2020-04-01|   0|     0|
|220|2020-01-01|   0|     0|
|220|2020-01-05|   0|     0|
|220|2020-01-10|   0|before|
|220|2020-01-15|   0|before|
|220|2020-02-01|   0|before|
|220|2020-02-05|   1|    at|
|220|2020-02-10|   0| after|
|220|2020-02-15|   0| after|
|220|2020-02-20|   0| after|
|220|2020-02-25|   0|     0|
+---+----------+----+------+
```